# Htaccess - Make the url longer

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

My current url: `http://example.com/view`

I want it to be: `http://example.com/index.php/home/view`

How can I do this?

I tried this but didn't work:

```
RewriteRule    http://example/$    http://example/index.php/home/$1    [NC,L]   # Process parrots
```

Comment: For all pages? or just `view`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php.*).*)$ /index.php/home/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The above code should work as required. Do make sure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

Comment: Thanks but there is a small issue.The domain I'm using to do this is an add-on domain, so I only want to affect the add-on domain, which is `example.com`. Do I just place `example.com` before the `^((?!index\.php).*)$` ?

Comment: @TaylorSwift Updated the reply above.

Comment: Hey sir, it's giving me a 500 error when I click a URL (that directs to example.com/page) or something else